# Something wrong with my loop or scanner

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, input, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to make a program that checks if a phrase is a palindrome or not. I first ask how many phrases they want to check, and then proceed to ask the user to type in the phrase.

For some reason, when I put the amount of phrases to 1 while testing, the program skips over asking user for user input, and goes straight to printing out the results..

I'm guessing that the problem lies in the For loop used to ask for user input but I'm not sure..

I'll paste the main method of the program, as I don't think the other methods will be necessary for now..

> ```
> public static void main(String [] args)
> {
>     //vars
>     String userInput;
>     //scanner
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>     //user input
>     System.out.println("\t Palindrome Checker");
>     System.out.print("How many do you want to test: ");
>     int many = in.nextInt();
>     //Array
>     String [] a = new String[many];
>     boolean [] det = new boolean[many];
> ```

```
    for(int i = 0; i < many; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Input phrase one at a time: ");
        a[i] = in.nextLine();
    }

    //object
    RecursivePalindrome pal = new RecursivePalindrome();

    System.out.println();


    //call methods
    for(int i = 0; i < many; i++)
    {
        a[i] = RecursivePalindrome.helper(a[i]);
        det[i] = pal.palindrome(a[i]);
    }

    //print results
    System.out.println("=========================== Results ============================");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf(" %-30s%-11s%n", "Phrase or Word", "Palindrome?");


    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {

        System.out.printf(" %-30s%-11s%n", a[i], det[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: plz provide you RecursivePalindrome class

Comment: Learn to use a debugger and step through your code - you'll solve your problem in no time...

Comment: Yes, Scanner does this. Make an empty call to `nextLine` immediately after calling `nextInt` and it will fix it. See [Skipping nextLine() after use nextInt()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-use-nextint)

Comment: Radiodef - yep, that did it :D